# Restricting a field to be an instance of a class AND implementing an interface at the same time

Tags: java, oop

Java allows to assign subclass instances to class-typed fields, for example:

```
public class BaseClass {

}

public class SubClass extends BaseClass {

}

public class Example {

    private BaseClass field1;

    public void assign(SubClass subclass) {
        field1 = subclass; // is OK
    }

}
```

Java allows also to use interfaces as types. If we have an interface `Fooable`,

```
public interface Fooable {
    void foo();
}
```

our `Example` class can have a field of type `Fooable`,

```
    Fooable field2;
```

That is, it is possible to assign to `field2` an instance of any class implementing `Fooable` interface.

But what if I want to tell the compiler that `field3` has to be **both** an instance of `BaseClass` and implementation of `Fooable` interface? So that, if there is a class

```
public class FooSubClass extends BaseClass implements Fooable {
    @Override
    public void foo() {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

, I could assign to `field3` instances of `FooSubClass` but not of `SubClass`?
Is it possible **without using generics** of any sort?

Comment: I think you can benefit simplifying your question.

Comment: Why would you avoid generics? One of the reasons to use Generics is precisely that, to tell the compiler (albeit at compile-time, not run-time due to Type Erasure) what it should be expecting and flag an error if something is wrong, so that you avoid having to track that bug down. Is it because you are using an older version of Java? otherwise why avoid it?

Comment: In my examples above, I didn't have to use generics to restrict `field1` to `BaseClass` (and its subclasses), and `field2` to instances of classes implementing `Fooable` interface. Why do I have to use generics when I want a combination of these restrictions?

Comment: @SamIam the "shorter" version of the question is expressed in the title.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do it like you are trying to.

You would need to define another class, perhaps an abstract class would suit you here:

```
public class abstract AbstractSubClass extends BaseClass implements Fooable {
    ...
}
```

Then `FooSubClass`:

```
public class FooSubClass extends AbstractSubClass {
    ...
}
```

Then your field is:

```
private AbstractSubClass field1;
```

Which will accept `FooSubClass` but not `SubClass`

Its the only way the compiler can guarantee that field1 will actually have implementations of all the required methods.

---

Here is a textbook example to illustrate:

```
public class Bird() {
    public void eat() { 
        ....
    }
}

public interface FlyingBehaviour() {
    void fly();
}

public abstract class FlyingBird extends Bird implements FlyingBehaviour() {
    ...
}

public class Eagle extends FlyingBird {
    ...
}

public class Penguin extends Bird {
    ...
}

FlyingBird bird = new Eagle();
bird.fly();

FlyingBird bird = new Penguin(); //Compilation Error - Penguins cant fly!
```

Comment: cowls has already answered your question, but in the event that do you do want to do this using generics, you can do `<T extends BaseClass & Fooable>`

Comment: Or you could try to "find out" manually, by casting to BaseClass, then to Fooable, and catching any ClassCastExceptions. Although it would be rather inelegant to say the least.

Comment: @cowls, this is definitely a solution. But isn't creating an abstract class solely for this simple goal a bit... excessive?

Comment: @Inego Nope I dont think so, but then I am a big fan of OO patterns. I have added a textbook example that may make more logical sense.

Comment: @Acapulco I wouldn't do that. It's a bad idea to use exceptions for business logic in addition to be inelegant (as you mentioned).

Answer (score 1):

There is no way in java to ensure a object field inherits/implements two different classes.
Assuming you have control of all the objects here, the easiest fix would be for your base class to implement Fooable.

Comment: Alas, I don't own the base class (it's `android.app.Activity`).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a assign-method for setting the fields, you can check if it is correct type of object using instanceof in that method.

```
public void assign(BaseClass baseClass) {
    if (baseClass instanceof foo)
       field3 = baseClass;
}
```

You may throw an exception if class not implementing foo is provided.

edit:
Doh, didn't see that the fix should be for compile-time.